# How can you pass hyphenated arguments (flags) to a template service unit?

Tags: systemd, systemd-escape

`myservice@.service` is my template service unit.

```
[Unit]
Description=my service unit     

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/username/scripts/myprogram.py %I
```

I want `%I` to be `--arg1 --arg2=/path/to/something`

I tried...

`systemctl start myservice@'--arg1 --arg2=/path/to/something'.service`

but it thinks `--arg1` is a bad option for `systemctl`.  And...

`systemctl start $(systemd-escape --template myservice@.service '--arg1 --arg2=/path/to/something'`

thinks `--arg1` is a bad option for `systemd-escape`.

Please help

Comment: Even if you did get it to insert `--arg1 --arg2=/path/to/something` somehow in the place of `%I`, I'd still expect it to be passed as single string, and not split into `--arg1` and `--arg2=/path/to/something`.

Comment: AFIK, %I is supposed to automatically unescape the string and then interpret spaced words as separate arguments.  The hyphens are the only stopping block for me right now.

Comment: Sadly that's not what [this user observed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450090/passing-flag-arguments-to-systemd-services/1450093#comment2533026_1450093) on a similar post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c %I` and let a shell expand the spaces=? I stumbled onto this trying to execute the instance name and this worked for me. [This issue from 2020 says](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14895) they will not implement multiple fields in templates and suggested by [a user](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14895#issuecomment-612270690) is using a script to parse the instance name for arguments. [Reply from keszybz (i think systemd devs)](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14895#issuecomment-594123923)

> This has come up before, and we decided not to allow multiple instances. If necessary, it is possible to encode multiple fields into one value in a unit-specific fashion, or use the instance as a key into some external storage, for example a directory on disk. Sorry.

Comment: I ended up passing the location of an `EnvironmentFile`.  I find it really bizarre the devs don't even consider this an issue.